# Undefined error when reading substring in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting this error on my React web application: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'substring').

```
const DocumentationDetail = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const { user } = useAuth();
    const id = router.asPath.substring(1);
    const { data } = useDocumentationGet(parseInt(id));

    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <title>{ data.title }</title>
            </Head>
            <main>
                <MainLayout>
                    <div className={styles.container}>
                        <h1 className={styles.title}>{ data.title }</h1>
                        <span className={styles.info}>Publicado { data.created_at.substring(8, 10) }/{ data.created_at.substring(5, 7) }/{ data.created_at.substring(0, 4) } por { data.author.name }</span>
                        <p className={styles.content}>{ data.content }</p>
                    </div>

                </MainLayout>
            </main>
        </>
    );
}
```

```
export function useDocumentationGet(id) {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getDocumentationRequest(id)
            .then(res => {
                setData(res.data);
            })
    }, [])

    return { data };
}
```

```
export async function getDocumentationRequest(id) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/documentation/${id}`,
      {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      },
    );

    if (response.ok) {
      return { data: await response.json() };
    }

    return {
      status: false,
    };
  } catch (err) {
    return {
      status: false,
    };
  }
}
```

If I comment the span tag, everything works fine, I don't get it why I only get this undefined error in this line. I also tried using: data ? data.created_at.substring(8,10) : "".... but I got blank spaces on the span line.

Comment: Where does `useDocumentationGet` come from?

Comment: added in the post

Comment: Your component renders initially with empty data. Then, much later, your fetch finishes, and calls `setData`. You need to handle the empty/loading case since your component can render with both types of data. This is one of the most common questions about React on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is being fetched after the component is rendered.

> i.e. `data.created_at` is empty at the time of render. There are many
> ways to fix this.

One of the way is to use `Conditional Rendering using short circuit`, i.e Rendering the component only once Data is ready to be used.
This way the component will render only when data is fetched.
Instead of just rendering the span tag, add a condition as mentioned below.

```
     {
         data?.created_at && data?.author?.name &&
             <span className={styles.info}>
                 Publicado { data.created_at.substring(8, 10) }/{ data.created_at.substring(5, 7) }/{ data.created_at.substring(0, 4) } por { data.author.name }
             </span>
     }
```