# Why is item inside .map() returning undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So im trying to loop the array of objects `items` inside `<Forecast />` component but for some reason `item` inside `.map()` is returning undefined even tho when i console.log it data is there but when i try to render for ex. `item.temp` it crashes and says undefined...

```jsx
import React from "react"

React
export default function Forecast({ items, title }) {
    console.log(items)
    return (
        <div  >
            <div className="text-white mx-8 mt-4">
                <div className="border-b ">
                    <h1 className="text-xl mb-2"> {title} </h1>
                </div>
                {
                    items.map((item, i) => {
                        console.log(item)
                        return (
                            <div key={i} className="flex justify-between my-6">
                                <div className="flex flex-col items-center">
                                    <span> {item.time} </span>
                                    <span>
                                        <img src={`https://cdn.weatherbit.io/static/img/icons/${item.icon}.png`} alt="" />
                                    </span>
                                    <span> {item.temp} </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

```jsx
import DefaultCitiesLI from "./DefaultCities"
import Inputs from "./Inputs"
import TimeAndLocation from "./TimeAndLocation"
import TempDetails from "./TempDetails"
import Forecast from "./Forecast"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { getCurrentData, getDailyData, getHourlyData } from "../api/weatherAPI"


export default function WeatherCard() {
    const [data, setData] = useState({})
    const [hourlyData, setHourlyData] = useState({})
    const [dailyData, setDailyData] = useState([])
    const [inputData, setInputData] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        async function getData() {
            try {
                const currentHourlyData = await getHourlyData(inputData)
                const currentDailyData = await getDailyData(inputData)
                const currentWeatherData = await getCurrentData(inputData)
                setData({ current: currentWeatherData })
                // setHourlyData({ hourly: currentHourlyData})
                // setDailyData({ daily: currentDailyData })
                setHourlyData(currentHourlyData)
                setDailyData(currentDailyData)
            } catch (err) {
                console.error("Error: " + err)
                return null
            }
        }
        getData()
    }, [inputData])

    console.log(dailyData)


    return (
        <div className="flex justify-center items-center mt-8">
            <div className="bg-[#1d2d44] rounded w-[600px] px-12 pt-12">
                <ul className="flex justify-center space-x-5">
                    <DefaultCitiesLI setInputData={setInputData} />

                </ul>
                <Inputs setInputData={setInputData} />
                {data.current &&
                    <div>
                        <TimeAndLocation weatherData={data.current} />
                        <TempDetails weatherData={data.current} />

                        <Forecast items={hourlyData} title="Hourly Forecast" />
                        <Forecast items={dailyData} title="Daily Forecast" />
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: This exact question is asked dozens of times a day on Stackoverflow. Here's a recent duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76402563/undefined-error-when-reading-substring-in-react

Comment: Also you initialize `hourlyData` to an object, which you can't map over `useState({})`